# Unable to enter CUPS admin section to add printer

Tags: cups

I am unable to add printer on CUPS page.

When I am trying to enter section, a password prompt appears:

[image]

root credentials are not accepted.

Also I have set separate password with

`lppasswd -a root`

and it is also not accepted.

How to overcome?

CUPS is 1.7.2